# AAD B2C Home realm discovery sample blowing up: Issuer validation failed

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We're getting an error running the "modern" home realm discovery sample for Azure AD B2C custom policies on GitHub: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern

We've created an AAD B2C tenant whose tenant ID is [B2C ID]. We've set up a plain AAD tenant with the name TestDomain.onmicrosoft.com, and we want home realm discovery to redirect the user's login there. In our custom policy we define a ClaimsProvider for the AAD tenant with the ProviderName = "https://sts.windows.net/[Issuer Guid]/". When we run the sample, the user types SomeUser@TestDomain.com and gets redirected to TestDomain's signin page. After successfully signing in, the custom policy blows up with this error:

IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/[Issuer Guid]/'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'null' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'https://sts.windows.net/[Issuer Guid]/[B2C ID]/"

In other words, even though our custom policy specifies the correct ProviderName in the ClaimsProvider definition, the B2C runtime is appending [B2C ID] to it and failing validation. Why? How do we fix this?

The entire ClaimsProvider definition is:

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
        <DisplayName>Login with AAD OIDC</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-OIDC">
                <DisplayName>Login with AAD (OIDC)</DisplayName>
                <Description>Login with AAD (OIDC)</Description>
                <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
                <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
                <Metadata>

                    <!-- <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.windows.net/jasjeetaad.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item> -->
                    <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/TestDomain.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>

                    <!-- <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/06a05be1-33df-4feb-9009-95c7a27a7a49/</Item> -->
                    <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/[Issuer Guid]/</Item>
                    
                    <!-- <Item Key="client_id">a963bb4d-6216-4904-b07d-251bfbfe19c8</Item> -->
                    <Item Key="client_id">[Provider's Client Id]</Item>
                    
                    <!-- <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">a963bb4d-6216-4904-b07d-251bfbfe19c8</Item> -->
                    <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">[Provider's Client Id]</Item>

                    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
                    <Item Key="resource">https://graph.windows.net</Item>
                    <Item Key="response_types">code id_token</Item>
                    <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
                    <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
                    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
                    <Item Key="ClaimTypeOnWhichToEnable">identityProviders</Item>
                    <Item Key="ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable">TestDomain.com</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="[Secret ID]" />
                </CryptographicKeys>
                <InputClaims>
                    <!--Demo: pass the login_hint to Azure AD home realm discovery page-->
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="login_hint" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AADOIDCIDP" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
                <EnabledForUserJourneys>OnItemExistenceInStringCollectionClaim</EnabledForUserJourneys>
            </TechnicalProfile>
        </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the latest AAD claims provider from our docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga

And add these lines in

```xml
<Item Key="ClaimTypeOnWhichToEnable">identityProviders</Item>
<Item Key="ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable">TestDomain.com</Item>

  <EnabledForUserJourneys>OnItemExistenceInStringCollectionClaim</EnabledForUserJourneys>
```

Comment: Now we get a different error:   "Message": "An error occurred while processing the request. Please contact administrator of the site you are trying to access.",
              "Data": {
                "IsPolicySpecificError": true
              },
              "Exception": {
                "Kind": "Handled",
                "HResult": "80131500",
                "Message": "A claim could not be found for lookup claim with id \"objectId\" defined in technical profile with id \"AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId\"

Comment: That tells me that the federated IdP step completed properly. Your issue now is that we are trying to read with objectId, but there wont be an objectId at this point in your journey. My sample uses the value of "isKnownCustomer" to determine that ([here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern/policy/SignIn_smart_HRD.xml#L366)). So your `isKnownCustomer` must be `false`.

Comment: `isKnownCustomer` only returns `false` if the [domainLookup](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern/policy/SignIn_smart_HRD.xml#L55) returned `false`.

Comment: I fixed so it skips Step 9 in your sample. Now I get this error: "[Policy] specifies the subject claim 'sub' which is missing in the claims collection."

Comment: Still waiting for an answer on that last error. Anyone?

Comment: We've discovered we get the same error when we try using the same AAD tenant with the plain-vanilla custom policy at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga. I'm going to open a new Stack Overflow issue on this. But I reply here would still be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use Social and Local Account starter pack? It’s required to do so at minimum. The reason why you get the “sub” claim error is because you aren’t reading the account from the directory at all. Either it’s read by alternativeSecurityId or by objectId. If you comment out step 9, then the prior read step by altSecId is also being skipped by its precondition, thus never reading a user in the directory to get an objectId to create the sub claim.

Comment: That was the problem. We were using the Local Account starter pack. We rebuilt the whole thing with the Social and Local Account starter pack and it worked. Thanks for help.